# How to root samsung galaxy J5 sm-j500h?

Tags: rooting, samsung

How to root Android 6.0.1 on samsung galaxy J5 sm-j500h?

Please.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is flashing a modified recovery with Odin.

1. Download :

   - [Chainfire autoroot](https://download.chainfire.eu/718/CF-Root1/CF-Auto-Root-e53g-e53gxx-sme500h.zip%3Fretrieve_file%3D1&ved=2ahUKEwiczvX5uIXaAhXLuxQKHTnVCHEQFjACegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1MIHACNOl9UXSDOmiWrNAx)
   - Odin
   - Samsung USB Drivers
2. Open Odin then click on AP, go where the root file was unzipped and select it.
3. Go to Settings > About >  Hit 7 times on Build number > Back in Settings > Developer's option then Disable OEM unlock
4. Switch off the phone, connect it in download mode (Volume + Home + Power buttons)

   4. Click on Start and wait until the phone reboot with Odin showing PASS.

Answer (score 0):

Let me present you `TWRP` + `Magisk`

### How TO:

1. Download and flash `TWRP` Recovery using [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j5/development/recovery-samsung-galaxy-j5-t3769408). After that
2. Download and flash `Magisk` using [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445)